# Systems root paths differ in Cordova file API and html image tag, src attribute

Tags: javascript, cordova, fileapi

I access files on two occasions:
1. Using the cordova file API (http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html), for example

```
fileSystem.root.getDirectory(PATH1, {create : true}, function(dataDir) {
    .....
});
```

or for specifying the source of an image in a html image tag like this

```
  $("#myimage").attr("src",PATH2+filename);
```

On my tablet, both specifications of PATH{I} differ in order to deliver the same place in my File System.

```
PATH1 = "myapp"; 
PATH2 = "/sdcard/"+PATH1+"/";
```

works (at least on my tablet).

However, after I installed the app on a smartphone, this system got out of order. I'd be glad if someone could tell me how to handle these file issues, as the inventor intended.